# Disable intent filter based on sdk version?

Tags: android

I have a BroadcastReciever with an intent filter for calendar changes along with other intent filters.

```
    <receiver android:name=".AppBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
        </intent-filter>
        ...
    </receiver>
```

Is it possible to disable the intent filter based on the SDK version? With SDK 24 and later, I should use JobScheduler instead.

Comment: Add version check in the `onReceive()` of the broadcaster

Comment: you can refer this-      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505357/disable-the-intent-filter-from-android-manifest-programatically

Comment: @MohdFaizan that seems to only apply to activities

Comment: @AshutoshSagar that's really not ideal since the app would be launched an extra time evey time the calendar changes

Comment: I don't see why we have to launch the app again @cambunctious. As If places series of Check for various versions it shouldn't be a problem. If you don't want to do something in a particular SDK version, then make a check for it and leave it empty or put it in else case.

Comment: @AshutoshSagar Android launches the app whenever a matching intent is broadcasted and the app is not already running. I'm looking for a way to prevent the app being launched altogether for certain intent filters on certain SDK versions. I don't think that is over-optimizing.