# USB Permissions without prompt

Tags: android, android-usb

I have 2 activities within my app. Say `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`.  `FirstActivity` is the MAIN and LAUNCHER activity. `SecondActivity` uses usb devices. I want the prompt for USB permission to appear only once within lifetime of the app.

If there was only one Activity, the following lines in manifest solved my purpose:

```
<activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />
</activity>
```

This was doing the following:

1. Launching FirstActivity whenever usb device (mentioned in xml) is connected is app is not already open.
2. Prompt for usb device permission appears only once.

How do I modify this to achieve the following:

3. If SecondActivity is already running and a new usb device is attached, I must be able to use the device without relaunching the app. So I have written a broadcast receiver for the same as follows:

   ```
   public class TriggerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) { 
           read connected usb devices and register serial port call listener back.
       }
   }
   ```

But the problem is `FirstActivity` gets relaunched again when usb device is attached while `SecondActivity` is running. How do I avoid this ?

Will add more information if needed. Would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "remove" intent filter `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />` from `FirstActivity` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408086/android-can-i-enable-disable-an-activitys-intent-filter-programmatically) question

**Update**

FirstActivity triggers on every `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` (even `SecondActivity` is running) because You set `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />` filter for it in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. So You should disable this filter when `SecondActivity` running. You can do this by that way:

1) add  (e.g. `AliasFirstActivity`) in `AndroidManifest.xml` to your `FirstActivity` and move `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />` filter to alias description (You should remove `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />`from `FirstActivity` description) like that:

```
        <activity-alias
            android:targetActivity=".FirstActivity"
            android:name=".AliasFirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                       android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity-alias>
```

2) add this code to `onCreate()` (or to `onResume()`) of `SecondActivity`

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        ComponentName compName =
                new ComponentName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".AliasFirstActivity");
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                compName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

to suppress intent filter `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` for `FirstActivity`. You should have in `SecondActivity` something like that:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        triggerReceiver = new TriggerReceiver();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        registerReceiver(triggerReceiver, filter);

        PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        ComponentName compName =
                new ComponentName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".AliasFirstActivity");
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                compName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

That should solve Your issue.
3) if it is needed, You can restore `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />` filter for `FirstActivity` in `onDestroy()` (or in `onPause()`) of `SecondActivity` by using this code:

```
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    ComponentName compName =
            new ComponentName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".AliasFirstActivity");
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            compName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: I did not understand this completely. If I create an alias with required activity filter, would subsequent app launches ask for usb permission again? Also, in that case where do mention the meta-data tag?  Can you please please add the activity alias code that you have in mind? It would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

> But the problem is `FirstActivity` gets relaunched again when usb device is attached while `SecondActivity` is running. How do I avoid this?

This is not hard to answer. In your *AndroidManifest.xml* you literally declare that your `FirstActivity` should be launched when the event `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` occurs.

If you want to handle this event in `SecondActivity` only, then you have to declare it in the manifest accordingly, for example:

```
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Now, whenever your USB device is plugged in, `SecondActivity` will be launched only. If `SecondActivity` is *already running*, then it won't be launched again (or multiple times) because of the attribute `android:launchMode="singleTask"` specified for `SecondActivity`. You can read more about the different launch modes [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) if you're interested.

Since you declared in your manifest that `SecondActivity` should be launched when a USB device is plugged in, the Android system will ask you the following question:

[image: USB Dialog]

After ticking the checkbox "Use by default for this USB device", it won't ask you again. Now, everytime you plug in the USB device, your `SecondActivity` will be launched and it will automatically receive the required USB permissions too.

Let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be helpful: 
[USB device access pop-up suppression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-supression/15151075#15151075)

Code snippet:

```
 public class UsbEventReceiverActivity extends Activity
     {   
        public static final String ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED = "com.example.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED))
            {
                Parcelable usbDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                // Create a new intent and put the usb device in as an extra
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE, usbDevice);

                // Broadcast this event so we can receive it
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            }
        }

        // Close the activity
        finish();
    }
}
```