# Android App Won't Remember USB Permission

Tags: java, android

I am trying to stop the app I am working on from asking for USB permissions each time the USB device is disconnected. I have followed: [USB device access pop-up suppression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-suppression) without much luck.

The app does remember the USB device until the device is unplugged.

If it matters I am trying to connect the app to an Arduino Teensy.

This is what my manifest activity looks like

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>     <!-- For receiving data from another application -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />

    </activity>
</application>
```

And here is my usb_device_filter file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="--hidden--" product-id="--hidden--" />
</resources>
```

Any help is welcome.

EDIT: I also look over at the Android Developer page and they say when using an intent filter for USB connections: *If users accept, your application automatically has permission to access the device until the device is disconnected.*

I would also like to point out that the suggested duplicate does not have the same issue as I am trying to solve. Their problem is having two activities while my problem deals with just one.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB Permissions without prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182096/usb-permissions-without-prompt)

Comment: No this is not a duplicate because I only have one Activity not two, which is the problem in the possible duplicate you suggested.

Comment: Does it occur also when you connect the USB to a linux pc (and windows)?

Comment: No my computer does not ask for permission when I connect the Arduino Teensy to it.

Comment: @Wowsk Does it make any difference when you check the checkbox in the permission popup ?

Comment: No it doesn't. Every time that the USB is disconnected it needs permissions again when reconnected, even after the checkbox is selected.

Comment: I have same problem, but only when device is restarted permission dialog shows up. in my case my device is rooted and app is installed as system app

Comment: @Wowsk I'm having the same issue. Did you find any solution to this yet?  I found an issue here suggesting its a problem in Android 7. What version of Android do you use? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77658221

Comment: We ended up opening the app automatically when the USB is inserted into the phone, because our project deals with the app being open all day. The app only asks for permission to use the USB once for the phone and remembers it now, as long as the user connects the USB before opening the app. Using Android 5

Comment: @Wowsk what if the device restart's?

Comment: It seems to remember. I can check for sure later today.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it does remember after a restart of the device. I added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up opening the app automatically when the USB is inserted into the phone, because our project deals with the app being open all day.

The app only asks for permission to use the USB once for the phone and remembers it now, as long as the user connects the USB before opening the app and the phone is unlocked. The phone even remembers the permission after the phone is restarted.

This is kind of a work around, but it works for our needs. Hopefully this will help some others with the same problem.

Comment: Could you share some working code that implements this?

Comment: I am also looking similar kind of solution for My application. Could you share your solution of code then It would be great for me.

Answer (score -1):

As the asker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182096/usb-permissions-without-prompt) says, For your perpose (if I understood correctly) the following should be enough. That's right that he had a different problem but he started hes question saying that for your case it's working.

```
<activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />
</activity>
```

Comment: I am using that code and it is not working. That is the problem.

Comment: I am also using this code and is does not work (android 10 / android 11) on zebra devices.